# How to update from RHEL6.1 to RHEL6.2 ,not RHEL6.3

Tags: redhat, yum, kernel

Now I'm using RHEL version 6.1, and would like to update to 6.2.
If I use the command ,

```
yum update
```

the OS version become 6.3.

so I used the command below

```
yum install kernel-2.6.32-220.23.1.el6
```

but, the version of '/etc/redhat-release' was still 6.1.

How can I update to 6.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yum update` should get you there. If /etc/redhat-release did not get updated it is probably a minor bug, and you should report this to Red Hat support.

Comment: `/etc/redhat-release` is in the `redhat-release` package, not the `kernel` package. This is why it wasn't updated.

Comment: thank you! I will try 'yum update redhat-release-server-6Server-6.2.0.3.el6'

Comment: @MichaelHampton you're right, I missed that part. Too used to blanket updates

Comment: @user1046827 just run yum update, with no additions, why do you need 6.2.0.3 when you have 6.3.x out?

Answer (score 2):

**This is a really bad idea**, since it is going to take you off the security/bug fix update path. If you decide to do this, you'll have to purchase [Extended Update Support](https://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux-add-ons/extended-update-support/) in order to get *supported* security and bug fix updates. If at all possible, you should update to the latest minor version. (They are roughly comparable to Windows service packs.)

With that out of the way...

You may be able to use the [create-release script](https://github.com/caulfie1d/satellite-scripts/tree/master/create-release) to create a channel for a specific Red Hat release. However, this script doesn't seem to have been updated in a couple of years, so it may not work for RHEL 6.

Another option is to download the DVD for the specific release you want, and use it as a local yum repository.

Finally, you can call Red Hat and take advantage of that support you're paying insane amounts of money for.

Comment: thank you for your replay. RHEL6.3 isn't still supported on my server.That's why I'd like to update to 6.2. I'll update to 6.3 after my server is supported.

Comment: Do you mean your application? The hardware should be fine.

Comment: I mean the hardware.R510(dell) doesn't support 6.3.(soon will be support)